Solana: How to handle 'Blockheight exceed' error?
Started to increasingly get this error recently and my app has become very unusable because almost 80-90% of the time the transactions are not going through.
Rpc being used - Helius.
Not very sure where I am going wrong.
My code.
  async sendAndConfirm(
    tx: Transaction,
    signers: Signer[] = [],
    options?: SendAndConfirmOptions
  ) {
    const usePreflightCommitment =
      options?.preflightCommitment ??
      this._confirmOptions.preflightCommitment ??
      "confirmed";
    const useCommitment =
      options?.commitment ?? this._confirmOptions.commitment ?? "confirmed";
    const useSkipPreflight =
      options?.skipPreflight ?? this._confirmOptions.skipPreflight ?? false;

    if (this._wallet) {
      try {
        if ((this._wallet as any).payer) {
          const latestBlockhash = await this._connection.getLatestBlockhash(
            usePreflightCommitment
          );
          tx.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash.blockhash;
          tx.lastValidBlockHeight = latestBlockhash.lastValidBlockHeight;
          tx.feePayer = this._wallet.publicKey;
          await simulateAndAddComputeBudgetUnits(
            this.connection.rpcEndpoint,
            tx,
            options?.computeBudgetMultiplier || this._computeBudgetMultiplier,
            options?.skipSimulation
          );
          return await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
            this._connection,
            tx,
            [(this._wallet as any).payer, ...signers],
            {
              skipPreflight: useSkipPreflight,
              preflightCommitment: usePreflightCommitment,
              commitment: useCommitment,
            }
          );
        } else {
          // Needed to enable BlockheightBasedTransactionConfirmationStrategy in sendAndConfirm.
          const latestBlockhash = await this._connection.getLatestBlockhash(
            usePreflightCommitment
          );
          tx.recentBlockhash = latestBlockhash.blockhash;
          tx.lastValidBlockHeight = latestBlockhash.lastValidBlockHeight;
          tx.feePayer = this._wallet.publicKey;
          await simulateAndAddComputeBudgetUnits(
            this.connection.rpcEndpoint,
            tx,
            options?.computeBudgetMultiplier || this._computeBudgetMultiplier,
            options?.skipSimulation
          );
          const signedTx: Transaction = await this._wallet.signTransaction!(tx);

          const txid = await this.connection.sendRawTransaction(
            signedTx.serialize(),
            {
              skipPreflight: useSkipPreflight,
              preflightCommitment: usePreflightCommitment,
            }
          );
          await this.connection.confirmTransaction(
            {
              signature: txid,
              blockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash,
              lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockhash.lastValidBlockHeight,
            },
            useCommitment
          );
          return txid;
        }
      } catch (err) {
        // Thrown if the underlying 'sendAndConfirmTransaction' encounters a failed tx.
        // We send an additonal request to fetch the failed tx logs and throw a parsed error.
        const match = err.toString().match(/Transaction (\w+) failed/);
        const txid = match ? match[1] : null;
        let errToTranslate = err;

        // If regex matches to "simulation", translate and throw original error.
        if (txid == "simulation") {
          throw translateError(errToTranslate, this._idlErrors);
        }

        // If txid is found, fetch failed tx logs and throw parsed error.
        if (txid) {
          try {
            const failedTx = await this._connection.getTransaction(txid, {
              commitment: "confirmed", // "confirmed" is the shortest commitment supported
            });
            const logs = failedTx?.meta?.logMessages;
            if (logs) {
              errToTranslate = new SendTransactionError(err.message, logs);
            }
          } catch (err) {
            console.error("Failed to fetch failed tx logs", err);
          }
        }
        throw translateError(errToTranslate, this._idlErrors);
      }
    }
  }


Things I have tried-

Multiple variants of priority fees. even tried extremely high still the same
skip preflight commitment

Would appreciate if someone can help me out in this. and also would be great to know if i can implement a workaround to improve the UX. because the transaction takes 120 secs to fail so not sure how to exit early and show error faster.
